# winforms C# Bunifu framework, не стыкуется Bunifupages c меню

Tags: c#

пишу десктоп приложения на winform с bunifu framework,(есть меню, несколько разделы, создал несколько страницы через bunifupages теперь как их стыковать между собой, помогите, что я не правильно передаю в pages

```
private void bunifuFlatButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            pages.SetPageByIndex(3)
        }

private void bunifuFlatButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pages.SetPageByIndex(5)
        }
```

Comment: У вас вопрос не получился. Боюсь, что никому не понятно, что значит `как их стыковать между собой`? И код приведенный вами ничего не иллюстрирует и не поясняет.

Comment: спасибо вам добрый человек, разобрался на документациях